# Is it possible to run Adobe After Effects (CS6 or later versions) under Wine?

Tags: linux, wine, adobe-after-effects

I have been unsuccessful trying to install Adobe After Effects on Linux using Wine.  If someone has done this successfully, could you share what steps are required beyond a "simple" installation in Wine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such question regarding the compatibility of programs with wine, you can always consult the official *App DB* at https://appdb.winehq.org

Specifically for *Adobe After Effects* direct your browser to https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=648 to reveal that all version from CS4 onwards are rated as *garbage*, i.e. not possible to use with wine:

[image]

Comment: Is there any other programs like Wine ? I want to try them.

Comment: @favarjooy86: There is a commercial version of wine, CrossOver, but I don't know anything about that one.